# NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET explanation

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, oracle10g

I must start that I am not Oracle user expert so I have some problems undestanding the basics :D. Our application is an MVC one with Nhibernate db connection. Problem lies when we try to save a characters like 'ѼóÂ' into a NVARCHAR2 field, they are saved as a question mark '?'. To fix this we changed to a different charset in database.

Here are our nls_database_parameters at installation:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE                   AMERICAN                                 
NLS_TERRITORY                  AMERICA                                  
NLS_CURRENCY                   $                                        
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY               AMERICA                                  
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         .,                                       
NLS_CHARACTERSET               EE8ISO8859P2                             
NLS_CALENDAR                   GREGORIAN                                
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD-MON-RR                                
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE              AMERICAN                                 
NLS_SORT                       BINARY                                   
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                HH.MI.SSXFF AM                           
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM                 
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT             HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR                       
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR             
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY              $                                        
NLS_COMP                       BINARY                                   
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE                                     
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP            FALSE                                    
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION              10.2.0.4.0
```

Originaly NLS_CHARSET was EE8ISO8859P2 and we changed it to: AL32UTF8 (works perfectly). Question is isn't NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET suposed to handle those special characters for fields like nvarchar2 ? If no then can someone please explain to me the its purspose?

Edit: NLS_LANG is set to: POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

National characterset was used in earlier times, i.e. before Unicode was available. The main idea was to have the common characterset where you store language independent items (include any source codes, etc.) for `VARCHAR2/CHAR` and have a customer-specific, i.e. language specific national characterset for `NVARCHAR2/NCHAR`.

In my opinion there is no reason to use it nowadays, since AL32UTF8 (or any other Unicode coding) is able to store any character anyway.

Maybe when you work in non-western languages a national characterset like `AL16UTF16` or `AL32UTF32` are slightly beneficial in terms of storage and efficiency.

Regarding you question: National Characterset `AL16UTF16` is able to store any Unicode character, so your polish characters should be no problem. However, maybe your client applications (or the selected font) is not able to display such characters

Comment: Thx for your input. Polish letters were not the problem here they stored fine. Letters in cyrylic were but if what you said its true, NLS_CHARACTERSET is the main thing to keep an eye on in the future, thank you again :)

Comment: *National Charaterset `AL16UTF16` is able to store any Unicode charater, so your polish characters should be no problem.* – Out of the three characters given in the question – ѼóÂ – only the second one is Polish one.